# Catch a process which last less than a second

Tags: linux, process

I'm trying to catch the exact moment a python app makes a system call to ldapsearch command and passes the user password in the command line itself.

The problem is that even with this code :

```
while :
do
     ps -ef | grep 'ldapsearch' | grep -v 'grep' >> out
done
```

It seems the process is live for such a short time that the ps call misses it every time.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can easyly print the log of the system calls with:

```
dmesg -w
```

with `-w` being the follow option.

Or if you know the PID of your process:

```
strace -p PID
```